# App Store submit : paths that are not allowed:( "AppThinning.plist" ) Build Visual studio for Mac

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

Got this
Dear developer,
We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Testflight evry test". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
This bundle is invalid - Your archive contains paths that are not allowed: ( "AppThinning.plist" )
Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,
The App Store team

The answer is this in Code 9, but hav to do this from VS for mac
[image]

Thanks Joacim

Comment: Did you get the email from Apple when you build the ipa via VS for Mac?

Comment: Try to report it to Microsoft via Help | Report a Problem.